# $f$ is continuous $\iff\operatorname{Fr}(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq f^{-1}(\operatorname{Fr}(B))$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

So I was reading Dugundji's topology and I found myself in trouble trying to prove the following.

> Prove that the following statemets are equivalent:
>
> - $f:X\rightarrow{}Y$ is continuous
> - $f(A')\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$ for each $A\subseteq X$
> - $\operatorname{Fr}(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq f^{-1}(\operatorname{Fr}(B))$

Where$A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A$, $\overline{A}$ is the closure and $Fr(A)$ is the boundary

I was trying to prove it using the other image and pre-image properties like
$$f(\overline{A})\subseteq\overline{f(A)}\text{ and }f^{-1}(\operatorname{int}(A))\subseteq\operatorname{int}(f^{-1}(A))$$
But so far I haven't been able to get anywhere, I would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: It would be helpful explaining the notation you used, i.e. what are $A',\overline A,\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ and $\operatorname{int}(A)$. Note that not everyone has a copy of Dugundji's topology at hand and Math.SE encourages self-contained posts.

Comment: @mrtaurho: While that is in general very good advice, in this case all four notations are pretty standard; the only one that I consider even slightly problematic is $A'$, and in this context it’s clearly the set of limit point of $A$, not the complement of $A$. I would expect anyone capable of answering the question to recognize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, then for all $B \subseteq Y$ we have $\partial f^{-1}[B] \subseteq f^{-1}[\partial B]$, where I use $\partial B$ for the boundary of $B$:

Let $x \in \partial f^{-1}[B]$. Let $O$ be an arbitrary open neighbourhood of $f(x)$. Then $x \in f^{-1}[O]$ and the latter is an open (as $f$ is continuous) neighbourhood of $x$ so $f^{-1}[O]$ intersects $f^{-1}[B]$ (i.e. some $x' \in f^{-1}[O]$ is in f^{-1}[B], so $f(x') \in O \cap B \neq \emptyset$) and it intersects its complement (so some $x'' \in f^{-1}[O]$ is not in $f^{-1}[B]$, so $f(x'') \in O \cap B^\complement \neq \emptyset$), and so $O$ intersects $B$ and its complement. As $O$ was an arbitrary neighbourhood of $f(x)$, $f(x) \in \partial B$ or equivalently, $x \in f^{-1}[\partial B]$, showing the inclusion.

And if we suppose the inclusion holds for all $B \subseteq Y$, $f$ is continuous:
let $O$ be open in $Y$ and we want to show that $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$. To this end, it suffices to show $\partial f^{-1}[O] \cap f^{-1}[O] = \emptyset$, so (striving for a contradiction) we assume we have some $x \in  \partial f^{-1}[O] \cap f^{-1}[O]$. The identity we assumed (applied to $B=O$) tells us that $x \in f^{-1}[\partial O]$ but then $f(x) \in O \cap \partial O$ and this contradicts that $O$ is open. So our assumption is indeed false, and $f^{-1}[O]$ is open and so $f$ is continuous.

The other argument involving limit points and closure is quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assume first that $f$ is continuous, and let $A\subseteq X$. You know that $f[\operatorname{cl}A]\subseteq \operatorname{cl}f[A]$, and $A'\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, so $f[A']\subseteq\operatorname{cl}f[A]$.

Still assuming that $f$ is continuous, let $B\subseteq Y$, and for convenience let $A=f^{-1}[B]$. Then

$$f\big[\operatorname{cl}f^{-1}[B]\big]=f[\operatorname{cl}A]\subseteq\operatorname{cl}f[A]=\operatorname{cl}f\big[f^{-1}[B]\big]\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B\;,$$

so $\operatorname{cl}f^{-1}[B]\subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{cl}B]$, and we also know that $\operatorname{int}f^{-1}[B]\supseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}B]$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{bdry}f^{-1}[B]&=(\operatorname{cl}f^{-1}[B])\setminus\operatorname{int}f^{-1}[B]\\
&\subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{cl}B]\setminus f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}B]\\
&=f^{-1}[(\operatorname{cl}B)\setminus\operatorname{int}B]\\
&=f^{-1}[\operatorname{bdry}B]\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, continuity of $f$ implies each of the other two statements.

For the reverse implications I’ll leave some of the work to you.

- Assume that $\operatorname{bdry}f^{-1}[B]\subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{bdry}B]$ for each $B\subseteq Y$. Use the fact that if $S$ is any set in a space, then $\operatorname{int}S=S\setminus\operatorname{bdry}S$, so show that $f^{-1}\operatorname{int}B\subseteq\operatorname{int}f^{-1}[B]$ for each $B\subseteq Y$, and conclude that $f$ is continuous.
- Now assume that $f[A']\subseteq\operatorname{cl}f[A]$ for each $A\subseteq X$. Use the fact that $\operatorname{cl}A=A\cup A'$ to prove that $f[\operatorname{cl}A]\subseteq\operatorname{cl}f[A]$ for each $A\subseteq X$, and conclude that $f$ is continuous.